# How to change the grid numbers in x direction when solving a 2D-PDE?

Tags: equation-solving, finite-element-method

I have found an example in the reference document. I want to change the grid numbers. Any one can help? The code is below.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
planeStrainOperator[Y_, vv_] := {
   Inactive[ Div][({{0, -((Y vv)/((1 - 2 vv) (1 + vv)))}, {-(Y/(2 (1 + vv))), 0}}.Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + Inactive[Div][({{-((Y (1 - vv))/((1 - 2 vv) (1 + vv))), 0}, {0, -(Y/(2 (1 + vv)))}}.Inactive[Grad][ u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}], 
   Inactive[ Div][({{0, -(Y/(2 (1 + vv)))}, {-((Y vv)/((1 - 2 vv) (1 + vv))), 0}}.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + Inactive[ Div][({{-(Y/(2 (1 + vv))), 0}, {0, -((Y (1 - vv))/((1 - 2 vv) (1 + vv)))}}.Inactive[ Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}]
   };
{uif, vif} = 
  NDSolveValue[{
    planeStrainOperator[1000, 0.33] == {0, NeumannValue[-1, y == 1]}, 
    DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0., v[x, y] == 0.}, x == 0]}, 
    {u, v}, 
    {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1}
    ];
mesh = uif["ElementMesh"];


Show[{
  mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements"]], 
  ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, {uif, vif}][
   "Wireframe"["ElementMeshDirective" -> Directive[EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[]]]]
  },
 ImageSize -> 300
 ]
```

[image]

I'm a beginner to PDE. Any one can suggest some good examples?
 Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{uif, vif} = NDSolveValue[
   {planeStrainOperator[1000, 0.33] == {0, NeumannValue[-1, y == 1]}, 
    DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0., v[x, y] == 0.}, x == 0]}, 
    {u, v}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1},
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement",
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Length" -> 0.05}}
       }
     }
   ];
mesh = uif["ElementMesh"];
```

and then

```
Show[{
  mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements"]], 
  ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, {uif, vif}][
   "Wireframe"["ElementMeshDirective" -> Directive[EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[]]]]
  },
 ImageSize -> 300
 ]
```

[image]

This refines both the x- and y-direction, but refining nonuniformly may cause severe degradation in accuracy.

For more details see e.g., [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview.html) and in particular the chapter [Passing Finite Element Options to NDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html#752095140).

Comment: Thanks ， Where can i find these hidden settings options ?

Comment: See the links I posted. Unfortunately, they are not documented directly in `NDSolve` because `NDSolve` is sort of a [swiss army knife](https://www.amazon.com/Wenger-16999-Swiss-Knife-Giant/dp/B001DZTJRQ) with many different `Methods`. The presence of `DirichletCondition` and `NeumannValue` automatically sets `Method ->{"PDEDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}`. As new user, this may be very puzzling. So, we have to refer to the FEM-guide in the documentation.